# Swipe through segment tabs - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

The code below uses segments from ionic 3. docs show the use of ngSwitch, ngModel. but I would like to simply swipe on the segment and switch to another segment tab. How can I achieve this?

I am not interested in swiping the tabs at the top but by swiping on the content i would like to change the segment tab.

[image: segment swipe]

```
<ion-content padding>

  <div>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="abc">
      <ion-segment-button value="Segment1">
        Segment Title
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="segment2">
        Segment Title
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </div>

  <div [ngSwitch]="abc">
    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'segment2'" class="list-fixed">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="assets/imgs/1.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2>List Item 1</h2>
        <p>List Item Subtitle</p>
        <button ion-button clear item-end>View</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'segment1'" class="list-fixed">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="assets/imgs/3.png">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2>List Item Title 1</h2>
        <p>Subheading</p>
        <button ion-button clear item-end>View</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
```

Comment: The segments of ionic do not support this. You have to implement it yourself. Tip: Angular/Ionic comes with HammerJS so you can use `panleft` and `panright` events for detecting the swipe gestures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Solution was to Add :

## .html file

```
//Add below code where you would like to detect the swipe from users input
// When user makes a swipe simply check and do the switch between Tabs.

(pan)='swipeEvent($event)'
```

## .ts file

```
pages: string = "pageA";

swipeEvent($e) {
    console.log($e.deltaX+", "+$e.deltaY);
    if($e.deltaX > 0){
      console.log("Swipe from Left to Right");
      this.pages = "pageB";
    }else{
      console.log("Swipe from Right to Left");
      this.pages = "pageA";
    }
}
```

Thanks to David's Comment